# Detecting which link is clicked with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

Here's the code:

```
for eachP in arr14:
            print('<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="{0}">{1} onclick=""</a><br />'.format(arr14.index(eachP), eachP))
```

Now, this code is in working state but, I want to alter the code and do something with the `onclick=""` attribute.

I would like to detect which link user has pressed and alerting the exact same link.

The code that I was writing was this:

`onclick="<script>alert(document.getElementById(" + arr14.index(eachP) + ");)</script>"`

Note: It's a .py file and I am using HTML, JS and Python(of course) inside it.

I am having problem with the onclick event. I would highly appreciate if anyone could help solve my problem ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can do that:

```
onclick="someMethod(this)"

function someMethod(input) {
    alert(input.id);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o18ofgu0/)

Comment: Thank you for helping but, I figured it out that my problem is something else. But, I accepted your answer as I learned something. Thank you again ^.^

Comment: So what the problem, may be I will help you?